# WSO2 ESB. Differences between v. 5.0.0 and v. 4.9.0. Content type text/xml and application/xml

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have a Proxy Service where inSequence has code like:

```
... 
<property name="messageType"scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
<property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
<payloadFactory>
parameters for query ....
</payloadFactory>
...
<send>
 <endpoint>
  <http method="PUT" uri-template="some url in WSO2 DSS/>
 </endpoint>
</send>
...
```

I use this Proxy Service in 2 ways.

First, call Proxy Service by Scheduled Task.

Second, call proxy service by:
WSO2 API Manager -> WSO2 ESB API -> my Proxy Service.

In WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 all worked properly.

In WSO2 ESB  5.0.0 second method works OK, but during first method I get error from WSO2 DSS:

```
DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:typeParam
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
```

In both cases payload is identical.

Since I changed text/xml to application/xml:

```
<property name="messageType"scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
<property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
```

both methods have been working properly..

It is interesting what's the cause?

I have found that axis2.xml has different message formatters for text/xml and application/xml, but there isn't any message builder for text/xml. Is it the cause?

Which behavior is right: in v.4.9.0 or in v.5.0.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the details raised since the payloads are the same you can investigate whether there is some difference between headers of 4.9.0 and 5.0.0 packs causes this issue.

For that you can try out enabling wire logs for synapse http transport

1. [esbhome]/repository/conf/log4j.properties file.
2. Uncomment log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
3. Restart the server.